# How to get the number of unique viewers for each month?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a single table and I need to count the number of unique viewers for each month.

```
SELECT month, location, COUNT(DISTINCT id) AS unique_viewers
FROM mytable
GROUP BY month, location
```

I need the results to only display the month, location, and the number of unique views based on the acct ids.

for example

```
Month  ID  Location
JAN   123   CA
JAN   456   CA
JAN   123   CA
```

I am having trouble counting based on the ID being distinct. I need my result to dislplay 2 unique views for Jan

Comment: GROUP BY, COUNT(DISTINCT userid).

Comment: What have you already tried ? If you haven't tried anything yet, please do start and then ask a question when you are stuck. Please provide some code. Please also take a moment to read [how-to-ask on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Most people here want formatted text, not images (or links to images.)

Comment: looks like your homework

Comment: thank you, sorry I am pretty new the community. I thought posting my code would be useless since I was thinking of doing a Union which didn't seem right.

Comment: As already said, sample data and expected result - as formatted text, and your current query attempt, is a good start!

Answer (score 0):

> I have a single table and I need to count the number of unique viewers for each month.

- "for each month" translates to `GROUP BY month` in SQL.
- "count the number of unique viewers" translates to `COUNT(DISTINCT viewer)` (or whatever that column is named).

The query:

```
SELECT month, COUNT(DISTINCT viewer) AS unique_viweers
FROM mytable
GROUP BY month
ORDER BY month;
```

> > I need the results to only display the month, location, and the number of unique views based on the acct ids.

*The* location? Which location? There can be multiple locations in a month. So this cannot be solved. You could display a list of locations instead using `GROUP_CONCAT`.

```
SELECT 
  month,
  COUNT(DISTINCT viewer) AS unique_viweers,
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT location ORDER BY location) as locations
FROM mytable
GROUP BY month
ORDER BY month;
```

Answer (score 0):

You have altered your request, contradicting "I need to count the number of unique viewers for each month". It seems you rather want to count the number of unique viewers for each month *and location*.

Use `COUNT(DISTINCT acct_id)`:

```
SELECT month, location, COUNT(DISTINCT acct_id) AS unique_viewers
FROM mytable
GROUP BY month, location
ORDER BY month, location;
```

Comment: Thank you! I just figured it out by doing it in Excel first like I normally do when I get stuck lol.